# So i have made a ssl certificate for my localhost, but the connection is refused,what should be done?

Tags: node.js, ssl, https, ssl-certificate

THIS PART OF THE CODE IS HOW I MADE AN SSL CERTIFICATE ===================
  C:\Users\avivo\Documents\https_app\server\ssl>openssl genpkey -algorithm RS -pkeyopt rsa_keygen_bits:2048 -out ca.key
    Algorithm RS not found

```
C:\Users\avivo\Documents\https_app\server\ssl>openssl genpkey -algorithm RSA -pkeyopt rsa_keygen_bits:2048 -out ca.key
................................................+++
.....+++

C:\Users\avivo\Documents\https_app\server\ssl>openssl req -new -x509 -days 360 -key ca.key -subj "/CN=Test CA/O=AAAA Teat Organization" -out ca.crt

C:\Users\avivo\Documents\https_app\server\ssl>openssl genpkey -algorithm RSA -pkeyopt rsa_keygen_bits:2048 -out server.key
......................................................................................................................................................+++
................................................+++

C:\Users\avivo\Documents\https_app\server\ssl>openssl req -new -key server.key -subj "/CN=localhost/O=AAAA Test Organization" -out server.csr

C:\Users\avivo\Documents\https_app\server\ssl>openssl x509 -days 360 -req -in server.csr -CAcreateserial -CA ca.crt -CAkey cs.key -out server.crt
Signature ok
subject=/CN=localhost/O=AAAA Test Organization
Getting CA Private Key
Error opening CA Private Key cs.key
14360:error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or directory:bss_file.c:406:fopen('cs.key','rb')
14360:error:20074002:BIO routines:FILE_CTRL:system lib:bss_file.c:408:
unable to load CA Private Key
unable to write 'random state'
//this the part of ssl ca and server certificate
erial -CA ca.crt -CAkey ca.key -out server.crt
Signature ok
subject=/CN=localhost/O=AAAA Test Organization
Getting CA Private Key
unable to write 'random state'

C:\Users\avivo\Documents\https_app\server\ssl>openssl genpkey -algorithm RSA -pkeyopt rsa_keygen_bits:2048 -out client.key
.......+++
...................................+++

C:\Users\avivo\Documents\https_app\server\ssl>openssl req -new -key client.key -subj "/CN=Test User/O=AAAA Test Organization/UID=testuser1" -out client.csr

C:\Users\avivo\Documents\https_app\server\ssl>openssl x509 -days 360 -req -in client.csr -CAcreateserial -CA ca.crt -CAkey ca.key -out client.crt
Signature ok
subject=/CN=Test User/O=AAAA Test Organization/UID=testuser1
Getting CA Private Key
unable to write 'random state'
//this is the client side
MAIN CODE IN INDEX.JS====================================================
var express=require('express'),
         fs=require('fs'),
      https=require('https'),
      path =require('path');
var app=express();
var directoryToServe='client';
var port=3443;
app.use('/',express.static(path.join(__dirname,"..",directoryToServe)))
var httpsOptions={
    cert:fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname,'ssl','server.crt')),
    key:fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname,'ssl','server.key'))
}
https.createServer(httpsOptions,app)
.listen(port,function(){
    console.log('serving the'+directoryToServe+'/directory at https://localhost:3443')
})
ERROR=======================
C:\Users\avivo\Documents\https_app\server>node index .js
serving theclient/directory at https://localhost:3443
^C
C:\Users\avivo\Documents\https_app\server>node index .js
serving theclient/directory at https://localhost:3443
^C
C:\Users\avivo\Documents\https_app\server>curl -k https://localhost:3443
curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 3443: Connection refused

C:\Users\avivo\Documents\https_app\server>node index .js
serving theclient/directory at https://localhost:3443
^C
```

//i have no idea as to why my isn't the server running,can anyone please help??

Comment: FYI what you're trying to achieve here is to build a reverse-proxy. It is very much recommended to use proven tools to do this instead of building your own; a great option is Nginx.

Answer (score 0):

Your Node application quits as soon as you hit `ctrl-c` to run the `curl` command. 
You either have to open a second terminal instance for `curl` or run the Node application as a process, by using something like [PM2](https://npm.im/pm2).

Comment: i added the curl command to check the connection status in promt, before using the curl ,prompt showed that the connection is alive but browser showed that there is no connection

Comment: Can you open a second terminal next to the running node one and run curl with a `-v` parameter? This gives us the full error so we can see what's going wrong